# Make markers layer permanent leaflet

Tags: dictionary, onclick, leaflet, marker, permanent

Simple enough to add markers to leaflet map using onClick but every time I refresh the markers have been removed and I have to start over. How do I make the markers permanent so that on subsequent refresh I can add to them? Here is the current code:

```
map.on('click', onMapClick);  
    
var layerGroup= new L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
    
function onMapClick(e){
    var layer = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(layerGroup); 
}
    
    
var layerGroup=L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
```

Comment: how do you load the markers/where do they come from? you probably need to save the new markers and load from where ever you saved them

Comment: The markers are loaded when I click on the map and stored in the var 'layerGroup'.  When I console log I see that for each marker I click to create, a new layer is created.  I thought by storing in the var that I was creating permanent layers but on refresh the layers (markers) are gone.  Other than storage in the var 'layerGroup', the markers are not saved for the next refresh.  I want to make the markers permanent so that each time I open the map the markers previously added appear.

Comment: you will have to figure some way of saving them, either backend (preferred) or some local storage/cache